# Comparing 2 tables (Insert, update or delete based on a secondary table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Imagine I have two database tables which both have similar structure. So one of them is source and another is target.
I want to compare them using unique ID, something like what `Redgate Data Compare` does, here is the scenario:

1. For every new record, an `INSERT` command be executed.
2. If a record does not exist in source table anymore, a `DELETE` command omits that record in target table.
3. If a row has changed in source, an `UPDATE` command be executed.

I have tried an stored-procedure to loop through every record in source and compare it with target but it doesn't seem to be ideal.

I want to know what is the key word for such a comparison in SQL and I was wondering if there is any prewritten query for such a cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MERGE command

check [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/) link for example